# How recursively call a command on linux shell

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to run a command(pycdc) on each files of all sub-folders

```
#!/bin/sh
uncompyle () {
pycdc "$1" >"$1"_dec
}
export -f uncompyle

find . -type f -name '*.pyc' -exec bash -c 'uncompyle "$0"' {} \;
```

But i got the error:

> ```
> Bad MAGIC!
> Could not load file ./file/my.pyc
> ```

How is the correct code?

Comment: Are you sure the pyc file is valid?

Comment: That is! there are some files not valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a function here.  Try:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec sh -c "pycdc {} > {}_dec" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be safer if you use process substitution and run it on a loop instead since your function won't be exported through `find`.

```
while read -r F; do
    uncompyle "$F"
done < <(exec find . -type f -name '*.pyc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -path '*.pyc' -exec bash -c pycdc "$0" >"$0"_dec {} \;
```

Comment: No input file specified
No input file specified
No input file specified
No input file specified
No input file specified
No input file specified
No input file specified
No input file specified